# Intermittent connectivity Issues between Azure VMs, through Public Cloud Service IPs

Tags: azure

Here is the story, I have one application deployed on one Cloud Service A and another VM under another Cloud Service B. Both Cloud Services are under the same affinity group (AG1) for example.

I have a web application deployed Under Cloud Service A, that communicates with a Redis instance deployed on the VM under Cloud Service B.

In my application configurations (deployed under Cloud Service A) I set the IP of my the Reids VM to be the Public IP of the Cloud Service B, and its working perfectly. Requests to Redis are being processed properly and data is stored and fetched between my app and the VM without problems.

recently I started getting some down time where the VM is not accessible via the public IP. I tried to ping the public IP and it doesn't work. as if the IP is not accessible. I tried to ping using the Private VM IP and it works, therefore I changed my config to use the private IP of the redis VM.

Is there anything wrong in my configuration? Or is it some instability in azure infrastructure. the Public IP was not changed, it just stopped being accessible. after few hours I try and it just pings back normally.

all my configurations are plain and clean, just cloud services in the same datacenter and Affinity Group. VM has Ubuntu Linux if that helps, installed using the default azure image. No ACL on the endpoints or anything

There is no logs to this case, the IP simply doesn't respond, there are no Windows or Linux error logs.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Services IPs in Azure are not static, and they change whenever you turn off the Cloud Service.

Instead of hard coding IPs inside your app config files, use the Cloud Service DNS address, that will never change, and no matter what the IP the Cloud Service is using, the DNS name will always translate to it.

Another work around that you may use is to set the Cloud Service to use a Static IP Address using PowerShell, read more about this here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/

Comment: Thanx man, problem is documentation says that the public IP of a cloud service is never changed unless you turn off the VMs inside, which didn't happen. Also they claim that access between cloud services using the public DNS will travel over the internet and incur network costs. :S

Comment: But it seems the best solution is create private network and put everything there.

Comment: That is entirely dependent on your solution design. In your scenario, if public access to Cloud Service B is not required, then by all means, configure the app running on Cloud Service A to use the private IP address of Cloud Service B, running all your VMs in a single Vnet is the optimum solution as they will appear as if they're inside a single LAN. you can even separate Vnet's and connect them using VPN if security is a concern. PM me if you'd like to discuss this more in details.